# Entlib Self Validation & EF Pocos

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, enterprise-library

I've been using the Enterprise Library validation block for a while now with tremendous success. However, I've run into a roadblock attempting to use SelfValidation with Entity Framework Code First. Here is some sample code:

**Entity**

```
namespace Data.Model
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using MetaData;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;

    [HasSelfValidation]
    [MetadataType(typeof(PersonMetaData))]
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Forename { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [SelfValidation]
        public void Validate(ValidationResults validationResults)
        {
            if (validationResults != null)
            {
                validationResults.AddAllResults(
                    ValidationFactory
                        .CreateValidator<PersonMetaData>()
                        .Validate(this));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Validation annotations** (no, I don't want a discussion on best practice buddy classes ;)

```
namespace Data.MetaData
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;

    public class PersonMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Forename is required.")]
        public string Forename { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required.")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All simple stuff but calling validation, the SelfValidation method Validate will not fire - the annotations are examined but any custom validation I might want to place in the SelfVAlidation method will be bypassed.

What gives? Works perfectly fine in Model / Database first.

Richard

Comment: If I use an Interface, everything is fine but if I use a buddy class, that's where the issue is. I wanted to use the buddy class to merge MVC annotations with my validations - keep everything in one place but maybe I need to stay with annotations on Interface properties.